# Issues getting a simple oraclize example to work, callback never executed

Tags: solidity, contract-development, evm, oracles

I have been trying to deploy and test the basic "SimpleDice" smart contract provided as an example from Oraclize.

I have had to adjust it to work with solidity 0.4.2 a bit, but maybe I am missing something, maybe Oraclize is bugging out.

The smart contract can be found here: https://testnet.etherscan.io/address/0xe1b0d1eecc126b96f94cf55e6cf525ccae4bf0d8

**EDIT: I have also deployed a second contract at https://testnet.etherscan.io/address/0xe25229cc19b5044f7cbe0c20abf9972c77b1e36c with more balance, this fixes the invalid jumps however *I STILL see no callbacks being executed***

I have the following code (note, usingOraclize.sol is the file located at https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/blob/master/oraclizeAPI_0.4.sol ):

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

import "usingOraclize.sol";

contract SimpleDice is usingOraclize {
    address owner;
    mapping (bytes32 => address) bets;

    function SimpleDice(){
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function() payable {
        if (msg.sender != owner) throw;
    }

    function __callback(bytes32 myid, string result) {
        if (msg.sender != oraclize_cbAddress()) throw;
        if (uint(bytes(result)[0]) - 48 > 3) {
            if (bets[myid].send(2 wei)) {
                log0("winner");
            }
        }
    }

    function bet() payable {
        rollDice();
    }

    function rollDice() {
        bytes32 myid = oraclize_query("WolframAlpha", "random number between 1 and 6");
        bets[myid] = msg.sender;
    }    

    function kill(){
        if (msg.sender == owner) suicide(msg.sender);
    }
}
```

**This code compiles and deploys just fine. However notice the following issues:**

1) The first time I call bet() it seems to work fine. **HOWEVER** as you may see, Oraclize never executed what it was supposed to and/or never called my __callback function

<strike>2) The subsequent times I call bet, the transaction fails with an "invalid jump destination"</strike>

3) The subsequent calls cost a lot of gas which is completely lost every time.

Does anyone have any idea what the heck is going on? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thomas from [Oraclize](https://www.oraclize.it) here.

The issue was geth-related and being experienced on the Morden testnet only (events filters were all messed up - the exact issue in geth is still being investigated).

We have enabled parity-based events listeners on the testnet as well - all the pending queries have now been processed (including yours), my apologies for the delay.

Comment: It happens, thank you though! Good to know I'm not going entirely crazy yet ;-)

Comment: Could this be happening right now with the Rinkeby network? I'm not getting a `__callback` trigger form my contract either : \

Answer (score 1):

Did you send enough Ether with your request? The costs do apply to Morden as well!

I had similar problems and had to send about 1 ETH with my request (at least it worked then, less might have been enough, but 1 ETH worked always). Of course, I only did this in Morden.

Comment: This may have changed since then, this should be handled automatically, if you check out the internal transactions you'll see the fee being sent.

Answer (score 0):

Make the constructor payable too. Refer the following code.

```
constructor() public payable{
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
```